# Linux kernel compiler for FriendlyARM

Tags: linux, gcc, compiler-errors, linux-kernel, arm

I'm trying to compile a Linux kernel for my FriendlyARM, but I'm getting this error:

```
kevin@kevin-VirtualBox:~/Desktop/FriendlyARM/linux-2.6.38-friendlyarm-newgccpatched$ make
make: arm-linux-gcc: Command not found
  CHK     include/linux/version.h
  CHK     include/generated/utsrelease.h
make[1]: `include/generated/mach-types.h' is up to date.
  CC      kernel/bounds.s
/bin/sh: 1: arm-linux-gcc: not found
make[1]: *** [kernel/bounds.s] Error 127
make: *** [prepare0] Error 2
kevin@kevin-VirtualBox:~/Desktop/FriendlyARM/linux-2.6.38-friendlyarm-newgccpatched$
```

Is there an easy way to resolve this?
I have never done this before, therefore, if I'm asking a stupid question, please forgive me.

Comment: Yes, make sure you have `arm-linux-gcc` installed and findable in `$PATH`.

Comment: ...or set CROSS_COMPILE appropriately for whatever ARM cross-toolchain you have. A simple web search for "ARM kernel compile" throws up tons of cross-compiling tutorials; I'm not sure this question is going to add much value to what's already out there.

Comment: im running the latest version of gcc-arm-linux-gnueabi how do i make it findable in $PATH ?

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you need to have arm cross compiler toolchain. For example `arm-none-linux-gnueabi`. You can download it [here](https://launchpad.net/gcc-arm-embedded)

When you have successfully installed the toolchain follow below steps to compile the kernel.

- cd to kernel directory
- execute
- `$ make ARCH=arm CROSS_COMPILE=arm-none-linux-gnueabi- defconfig`